# ListView -images get shuffled or changed when i scroll in list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter, shuffle

my images get shuffled or changed when i scroll in list view....... Images get shuffled when i scroll down and keep on changing own its own I have a custom listview adapter, and when I scroll down/up the list, images get shuffled and I don't know what to do.

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private static ArrayList<String> searchArrayList;
     SQLiteDatabase database;


     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> listid = new ArrayList<String>();

     public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> results) {
      searchArrayList = results;
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      database = context.openOrCreateDatabase("ORCL", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     }

     public int getCount() {
      return searchArrayList.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
      return searchArrayList.get(position);
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
     }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ViewHolder holder;
      if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.homelistvwlyout, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       holder.txtvwid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

        holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position));
//      Cursor cursorQuote = database.rawQuery(
//              "SELECT * FROM  Qotestable where Notification_Status =1",
//              null);
        Cursor cursorQuote = database.query("Qotestable", null,
                "Notification_Status" + "=1", null, null, null, "Quote_ID"
                        + "DESC");



        if (cursorQuote.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                list.add(cursorQuote.getString(3));
                listid.add(cursorQuote.getString(0));
            } while (cursorQuote.moveToNext());
        }
        //Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder()); 
        String s = list.get(position);
        if (s.contentEquals("1")) {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.onestaron);

        }else  if (s.contentEquals("2")) {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.twostaron);
        }else  if (s.contentEquals("3")) {
            holder.iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.threestaron);
        }
        holder.txtvwid.setText(listid.get(position));

      return convertView;
     }
 static class ViewHolder {
  TextView txtName,txtvwid;
  TextView txtCityState;
  ImageView iv;
  TextView txtPhone;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you query the database every time `getView()` is called? Besides that it's waste of performance, `list` and `listid` grow infinitely large.

Comment: i have tried in outside the getview ,but the result is still same,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put space between `"Quote_ID"` and `"DESC"` so your collection comes unordered. Change `"Quote_ID" + "DESC"` to `"Quote_ID DESC"`.

Also you query the database every time getView() is called. Besides that it's waste of performance, `list` and `listid` grow infinitely large. At least you should clear them. And if you don't want to update contents on the fly you should move this code out of `getView()`.

**UPDATE**
Can it happen that `cursorQuote.getString(3)` is not equal to either "1", "2" or "3" for a given `position`? In that case you don't assign image at all and it remains as it was in the convertView.

Comment: @user3098271 found another possible issue, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess ! ... try using ... if your `listview` size is not huge .... to preserve the `insertion` `order` in `activity` and `adapter`

---

In both `Activity/fragment` and `adapter`

**Instead of** ::

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Use** ::

```
 LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

---

Comment: it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Please check your listview height.....It shouldn't be wrap_content.....it Should be match_parent.
as follows,

```
<ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" /> ///////HEIGHT SHOULD BE MATCH_PARENT////
```

Comment: the getview() method is called many times while creating and scrolling.....so remove the query to database from getview()

Comment: i have fixed this problem by putting else condition